# Example of complex similarity computations in ArangoDB?

Tags: graph, arangodb, arangojs, multi-model-database

I am new to ArangoDB and have been reading through the documentation and examples available online for a few days now. However, I am not able to formulate a query to do a complex calculation using AQL. Looking forward to some examples that can help.

For starters, an idea on what's the best way to solve a case such as: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-cookbook-similarity-calc.html#d5e4728 would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right. Our [documentation is lacking examples](https://docs.arangodb.com/Aql/NumericFunctions.html), we will fix this. Its used like that:

```
db._query('RETURN SUM([1,3,5*7])/3.5')
[ 
  11.142857142857142 
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! :)

Comment: on a related note, can you also give an example for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35640507/arangodb-how-to-perform-computations-in-graph-traversals?

Comment: Thanks a lot once again for the incredible efforts you guys are putting in.